# Trello client.js won't authenticate when testing on localhost

Tags: trello, trelloapi

I was attempting to work on an [old(ish) project](https://github.com/ZMYaro/GrocerieZ) that uses the Trello API.  Running the same code in a local server like when I initially developed the project now no longer works.

When I attempt to authenticate with Trello, the initial authorization dialog appears as expected, and upon accepting, the dialog redirects to `https://trello.com/1/token/approve`, but it hangs on a blank white page, and the authentication flow never completes.  I am running the identical code from when I initially developed the app, which is the code currently running as expected on my website.

I tried using the same API key as the live instance, adding both `http://localhost:8080` and `http://127.0.0.1:8080` to the list of allowed origins for the key with no luck.  I also tried running the local server on port 80 (and adding `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1` to the allowed origins); again, no luck.

I don't think I have worked on this project since they moved API keys from the old [app key page](https://trello.com/app-key) to the [power-up admin portal](https://trello.com/power-ups/admin); I am not sure whether something changed in that migration I wasn't aware broke local development.